# Unable to run a react app inside docker container using nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, deno

I'm trying to run a react app inside a docker container using DOCKER-multistage.
The server is written on deno and I tried to add nginx server to dispatch the requests from the frontend to the server.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
# install curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip sudo nginx

# install node.js v16.x
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# install postgresql
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  curl vim wget \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev &&\
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata nodejs yarn postgresql postgresql-contrib

# install deno v1.21.3
RUN curl -fsSL https://deno.land/install.sh | sh -s v1.21.3
ENV DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
ENV PATH="${DENO_INSTALL}/bin:${PATH}"

# Install denon
RUN deno install -qAf --unstable https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnmrts/denon/patch-4/denon.ts

# The working directory of the project
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the app package and package-lock.json file
COPY frontend/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


# Copy the backend directory
RUN mkdir backend
COPY backend/deps.ts ./backend/deps.ts 
RUN cd ./backend && deno cache --unstable deps.ts

ADD backend ./backend

EXPOSE 3000

COPY ./script.sh script.sh
CMD ./script.sh
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create the database in postgres
service postgresql start && su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password 'postgres';\"" \
  && su - postgres -c "psql postgres -c \"create database db;\""

# start nginx
sudo service nginx start


# Populate database tables
cd backend && deno run --unstable --allow-env --allow-net database/seeds.ts && denon start &


# Wait for any process to exit
wait -n
  
# Exit with status of process that exited first
exit $?
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
   listen 3000;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000/;
  }
}
```

I build the image :

```
docker build . -t server-app
```

And I create a new container:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 server-app
```

Everything is working and the deno server is listening on the 5000 port but when I run the app on `localhost:3000/` I got this error:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

What's wrong with the config I have done?

Comment: That seems like it should be three separate containers.  What listens on port 5000?  Do you have evidence that it's actually running?  (If it was its own container, you could look at that specific container's `docker logs`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I added a screenshot of the logs displayed inside the docker container.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the actual logs instead?  You should almost never attach screen shots of terminal windows to questions, since they're hard to read and search for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the nginx.conf:

```
server {
   listen  3000;
   server_name localhost;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
   }
   location /api {
      rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
   }
}
```